# Execute code before reaching the controller's code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My intention it's to create a *MasterController* that decides what configurations will use depending on the URL parameters.

1. My first idea was to create a *MasterController*. All requests to the server would be redirected to this controller and then, this *MasterController* would decide wich controller to use, and redirect to it. The problem would be that this would  make too many requests.
2. My second idea was to call a function in the beginning of each controller that redirects to the correct controller if necessary. The problem would be the same: it would increase the number of requests.

Concrete example: Imagine that I have the followings URLs:

> http:\\myapp.com\?showController1=true
>
> http:\\myapp.com\abcd?showController1=true

When the server receives the request, I want the final result be the same: show *Controller1*, independently of the request being to `homeController` or `abcdController`.

To make this work, before witch controller is reached, I need to decide which controller will be called dependedind on the url parameters. But I want to minimize the number of requests made between the server and the browser.

It is possible to implement this without making extra requests?

Comment: You might want to look more at how routing works and override that instead, it sounds more likely to be the thing to change for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Inherit from your base controller (masterController) and make your check there. Or apply a custom filter and override OnActionExecuting

Comment: Please, be more concrete. What does "decides what configurations will use" exactly means? Why after saying this you say: "redirects to the correct controller"? If you explain exactly what you intend, what is configuration, how the url looks like, where are the parameters, whan happens when parameters change and so on, it's mor possible that we can help you.

Comment: I made some changes, trying bring more information to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the question edition, I see that most probably it's possible to solve this problem simply by specifying the correct routes.

The routing happens before the controller which will handle the request is chosen an instanced.

The result of the routing is to choose a controller, an action, and get parameters from the URL. So, specifying the correct routes would allow you to choose the rigth controller in a non-invasive way (which was what the original answer did). But, this would only work more if you specified the parameters as URL segments, instead of query string parameters. If not, fall back to the original answer.

### Original answer

Although the question isn't very clear, it looks like you want to choose a particular controller depending on the URL. One way of doing so is implementing your own [IControllerFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory(v=vs.118).aspx), and register it as the ASP.NET MVC controller factory, likt this:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

In the implementation of your custom `MyControllerFactory`, you have to implement this members:

- `CreateController(RequestContext, String)`: Creates the specified controller by using the specified request context.
- `GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext, String)`: Gets the controller's session behavior.
- `ReleaseController(IController)`: Releases the specified controller.

Particularly, the first method receives the controller's name, and information including the [RouteData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata(v=vs.110).aspx) - which includes parameter information - and the `HttpContext`, and returns an instanced controller.

In general it's not a good idea to do this, because MVC stops workin "as expected", and someone which maintains this project later on will have trouble understanding what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and review my question. The original answer it is perfect for my issue.